# Vertical Scrollbar for Eclipse GridData

Tags: java, eclipse, scrollbar

I have the following java code in an eclipse application:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException;

public void setupList(Composite parent, List items) throws OdaException {

GridData myGrid = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
List myList = new List(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
myList.setLayoutData(myGrid);
myList.setItems(items);

}
```

In my program, the number of items exceeds the maximum height of the window, but no vertical scrollbar appears.

I thought that passing the SWT.V_SCROLL parameter to the list would create a vertical scrollbar, but it didn't work.

What am I missing to make the GridData's List have a vertical scrollbar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The following line needed to change:

```
GridData myGrid = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH); // FILL_BOTH instead of FILL_HORIZONTAL
```