# Vertical scroll bar for SWT list widget

Tags: swt, scrollbar, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Following is my code:

```
Group leftGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);

leftListWidget = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(leftGroup,
            SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);

leftListWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

From the above code I though that that if I added `V_SCROLL AND H_SCROLL`, it would add both horizontal and vertical scroll bar in my list widget. However I cannot see any scroll bar. When I increase the number of records in the list, it just increases the size (length) of the list.
Is it a problem with scrolling OR with setting the length of list widget?

Answer (score 4):

This is the course of list in SWT!!!

You need to create your own widget (check i.e. http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11489/Custom-SWT-List-Box) and manage there you scrollable components.

Comment: Or just use a table or a tree :)

Comment: Simple and effective!

Comment: Wrong. You do NOT need to create your own widget. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284864/vertical-scrollbar-for-eclipse-griddata All parents of the list can be either Grid or Fill layout. If Grid, you must set the layout data to GridData.FILL_BOTH.